# Revert changes in git to particular time

Tags: git

I am in a git repo where I messed up a few things I want to revert it to same state as in the morning , I remember there is a command to do it but not able to find that, Can anyone please help?
Thanks

Comment: Does this solve your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4114095/11074646 ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I revert a Git repository to a previous commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114095/how-do-i-revert-a-git-repository-to-a-previous-commit)

Comment: I want to go to a state in morning , I dont really know what is last commit at that time, So i want a git command to take the repo to previous state using time (like to a state before 3 hours)

Answer (score 1):

You can checkout to the commit id, after which you have messed things up.
That will detach your HEAD. After that, you can create a new branch from there and proceed.

This answer might help you with more detailed explanation --> https://stackoverflow.com/a/4114122/13852431

Comment: Problem is I dont know last commit because i pulled code after that , so i want command to take repo to previous state using time

Comment: ```git checkout `git rev-list -1 --before="Jul 02 2020" master```

This one can detach your head to a commit at some date, but I am not sure about time level precision here.

Reference -
https://www.endpoint.com/blog/2014/05/19/git-checkout-at-specific-date

Answer (score 0):

you can use command:

> git reset --hard branch_name@{"15 minutes ago"}